# html5 Input type=email Not Appearing in request.form collection

Tags: html, asp-classic

Using classic ASP (vbScript) on iis7:

I am trying to upgrade a front-end web form from XHTML to HTML5 tags.

I have been successful in all but one place - that is, with:

```
<input type="email" value="name@email.com" name="myEmail" />
<input type="text" value="some name" name="myName" />
```

The issue is that when posting the form to a .asp script which loops through the request.form collection, the input from the `type="email"` form item is not present in the collection. The item just doesn't exist in the collection.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. My issue was actually with the .js code which first accepts the input from the form (and then passes it to the .asp page for processing) in an ajax-style manner.

There was some hardcoded input types in the js and it had not been updated to accept the html5 data types.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to look at the question.